# How to include a variable in api call in python?

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to implement a searchbar in django. I am getting the search input as `movie_title` from the html form. Now, how do i include it in my api call ? I tried with curly braces. Here's is the code

```
def searchbar(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        movie_title = request.GET.get('movie_title')
        searched_movie = requests.get(
            'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=9a63b7fd&t={movie_title}')
```

Comment: use f strings `f""`

Comment: just concat the string with the variable

Comment: thanks , my python is a little rusty. figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the url as an object using `f-strings` (one of the ways) and pass that to the `get()` method:

```
url = f'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=9a63b7fd&t={movie_title}'
searched_movie = requests.get(url)
```

---

Note: You don't need to create a different object and can directly use:

```
searched_movie = requests.get(f'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=9a63b7fd&t={movie_title}')
```

The above approach helps with readability when there are several dynamic attributes involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use { and } in your query string you can simply write

```
searched_movie = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=9a63b7fd&t={'+movie_title+'}')
```

Otherwise you can write

```
searched_movie = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=9a63b7fd&t='+movie_title)
```